# Laravel pivot table permissions check

Tags: list, laravel, roles

When I click on the Role detail lists all the permissions .

My Controller :

```
    public function permissions($id)
{
    $all_permissions = Permission::all(); // All permissions

    $role = Role::with('permissions')->where('id', '=', $id)->get(); // Role and role permissions

    return view('auth.permissions',compact('role','all_permission'));
}
```

All permissions in the role of pivot tables list the permissions I want you to be selected

[image]

My View file:

```css
@foreach($role as $rol)

{{ $rol->name }} 
<tbody>
@foreach($all_permissions as $permision)
    <tr>
        <td> {{ $permision->id }} </td>
        <td> {{ $permision->name }}</td>
        <td> {{ $permision->label }} </td>
        <td> {{ $permision->updates_at }} </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="make-switch" checked data-size="small" data-on-color="success" data-on-text="YES" data-off-color="danger" data-off-text="HAYIR"> </li>                                    
        </td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach   
</tbody> 
@endforeach
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: all the permissions list the permissions for that role, I want to ask you to come selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "contains" method will do what you have wanted:

This is a sample from one of my live projects:

```
@foreach ($permissions as $permission)
<tr>
    <td><label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
    {!! Form::checkbox('permissions['.$permission->id.']', $permission->id, $role->permissions->contains($permission->id)) !!}<span></span></label></td>
    <td>{{ $permission->title }}</td>
    <td>{{ $permission->slug }}</td>
    <td>{{ $permission->description }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```